# Is there a word to describe "one who is in passive opposition to an established order or government?"

Tags: single-word-requests

I read that [malcontent](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/malcontent), a *noun* in grammatical sense, is "one who is in active opposition to an established order or government," but is there a word to describe "one who is in **passive** opposition to an established order or government?"

A bit of searching last turned to *[disillusioned](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/definition/disillusioned)*, an *adjective* — "She became more and more *disillusioned* with politics" —, but I'm looking for a *noun* and *disillusioned* is not, whereas *malcontent* is.

Thus, my question is, is there a word to describe "one who is in **passive** opposition to an established order or government?"

Comment: It's not one word, but how about "half the population"! ;-)  But, seriously, in a bi- or tri-partite democratic system, aren't all hose who voted for the parties *not* in power "in passive opposition to [the] government"? *Active* opposition is obvious, but what do you mean by *passive* opposition?

Comment: A "miliband"? But seriously, although I'm perfectly familiar with the word malcontent, I've never actually spoken it and probably seen it written down once a year or less. In any political arena words like rebel, opponent, critic, even enemy are used. I'm not even sure about that definition that malcontents are in active opposition. If I read "Tory malcontents will not be appeased by this new bill" I would think of malcontents as being unhappy generally with the way things are going but grumbling and muttering rather than actively opposing.

Answer (score 3):

I think you want

> **dissident** *noun* a person who strongly disagrees with and criticizes their government, especially in a country where this kind of action is dangerous

*Oxford Advanced American dictionary*

> **dis·si·dent** n. One who disagrees; a dissenter.

*thefreedictionary.com*

Comment: I thought of that too but you can be an agressive dissident or dissidents may become aggressive.

Comment: If a movie title was The Dissident, I would expect to see a lot of hostility.  Not some guy marching with a sign, right?

Comment: I am not saying you are wrong.  Just saying what I think when I hear the word.  I might be wrong.  Certainly like it better than satyagrahi - which isn't an english word.

Comment: One can certainly express dissent using non-violent means. The word *dissident* has often been used to describe scientists, philosophers and free-thinkers who were against the Soviet regime, for example.

Comment: Relevant wikipedia link: [List of Chinese Dissidents](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Chinese_dissidents) I see very few violent dissidents on that list…

Answer (score 1):

Consider ***satyagrahi*** in the sense of passive but 'constructive' opposition

> an exponent of nonviolent resistance, esp as a form of political protest

although Gandhi did not strictly coin the term [***satyagraha***](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Satyagraha) to mean *passive resistance*, it has come to mean nonviolent resistance in a broad context, and he was himself given to using the terms interchangeably.

A close term that would fit your context I think is [***meliorist***](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/meliorist?s=ts).

Comment: Is that really english language?

Comment: Satyagrahi or meliorist? they both are very much so.

Comment: @RyeBread: Satyagrahi and Satyagraha are present in many standard dictionaries. They are of Sanskrit origin, but they are acceptable English words. The only irony is that these words owe their presence in the dictionary to British imperialism!

Comment: I feel that using Sanskrit words is a slippery slope.  I am a French speaker and I can often think of a word that would work and often I could prove it out or something similar in an English dictionary.   The fact is you would be hard pressed to find it used unless it is an article about Gandhi.

Comment: But it is an English word

Comment: Reminds me of Thoreau's *civil disobedience*, too.

Comment: @RyeBread: But isn't that the way English works, by absorbing words from many different cultures and regions? Satyagraha is an English word, as is Ubuntu (from Xhosa), Weltschmerz (from German) or ménage à trois (from French)

Comment: @RyeBread Should we also stop using words such as *avatar*, *aryan*, *bandana*, *shawl*, *crimson*, *jungle*, *jackal*, *guru*, *shampoo*, *cheetah* (and many, many, more) because they're also of Sanskrit origin?

Comment: While ghoppe has an excellent point, if the purpose of the word is to communicate something to an audience, it helps to weigh the options of using a very good word that no one will understand or opting for another word or two that will clearly communicate your meaning.

Comment: Luckily this seems to accomplish both

Comment: @ghoppe - no because those words have become part of the english dialect, adopted from sanskrit.  In no way has satyagrahi become part of the english language other than being in a huge dictionary (probably because of the Gandhi reference).

Answer (score 1):

This is a ***conscientious objector***, [in many instamces](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conscientious_objector)

Answer (score 0):

I would say **hippie**, non-conformist, protestor, or objector.

Answer (score 0):

Anarchist may be the word you are looking for.

Comment: An [anarchist](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/anarchist) is in opposition to ***any*** established order or government, not just a particular one.

Comment: the question asks the word for a person who is in opposition to any established order or goverment. So, Anarchist is the same as explained by you.

Answer (score 0):

What about an **armchair activist**? It's somewhat derogatory but it may fit.

Comment: An armchair activist isn't passive. Many bloggers are armchair activists, and are in fact malcontents. That being said, I think the problem may be with the question.